# Send Email using SMTP in C# + Template Processing Mail Merge

Tags: c#

Currently i am using SMTP Client to send email in C#.
I have one email template defined in which i replace the value at run time.

```
MailDefinition mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
mailDefinition.BodyFileName = "~/Email-Templates/File.html";
mailDefinition.From = "abc@gmail.com";
//Create a key-value collection of all the tokens you want to replace in your template...

ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
replacements.Add("<%FirstName%>", "abc");
replacements.Add("<%LastName%>", "xyz");
replacements.Add("<%ManagerName%>", "Tom");            
replacements.Add("<%Address1%>", "USA");
replacements.Add("<%Address2%>", "USA");
replacements.Add("<%City%>", "uk");
replacements.Add("<%State%>", "uk");
replacements.Add("<%Zip%>", "9876543");

string mailTo = string.Format("{0} {1} <{2}>", "abc", "xyz", "abc@gmail.com");
MailMessage mailMessage = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(mailTo, replacements, this);
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "test site");
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
mailMessage.Subject = "User Details";
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "aaaaaaaa"),
    EnableSsl = true
};

client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Template looks like this :

```
Hello <%FirstName%> <%LastName%>, 
Thank you for creating an account with us. 
Here are your details: 
Your Manager is <%ManagerName%> 
<%Address1%>, 
<%Address2%> 
<%City%>, <%State%> <%Zip%> 
Thank You, 
abc
```

Now my question is in future i want to add newfield to the email template , i need to add the same to my code and rebuild the system, this is what i dont want , i dont want to build my system everytime. 
Is there a way or some other approach where i need not to build the system everytime ?
I can configure this from some where else ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the data for the fields? From a database where you could use the column names? Or store name/value pairs in a database?

Comment: @HABO : Can you please ellaborate on your approach of column names and name/value pairs ?

Comment: You could do something as simple as `<%ColumnName%>` picks up values from column `ColumnName` in a (predefined) database table or query. It can be extended to allow `<%TableName:ColumnName%>`, though that opens a _large_ security hole if you don't restrict the tables. `<%SP:ColumnName%>` could pick a column returned by a stored procedure in the database. Or you could just hand off the email template to a stored procedure and let it perform the substitutions. That would let you add new fields by replacing the SP without changing the C# code.

Comment: A database can handle name/value pairs, though typically not as efficiently as simple columns. You might have a `Clients` table (ClientId, Name, Address, ...) and a `ClientAttributes` table (ClientId, AttributeName, AttributeValue). You can pick up all of the name/value pairs of attributes for a given client by ClientId and then match them to the fields in the email template by AttributeName. It makes it easy to add custom attributes since it's just another name/value pair, not a new column or table. The template can have a _null_ option, e.g. `<%ShoeSize|n/a%>` to display "n/a" if _null_.

Comment: If i hand off the email template to SP and let it perform the substitution.....how substitution will be performed by SP..What code will be used ?

Comment: TSQL could grind through it, though it wouldn't be fast. Parsing isn't TSQL's strong suit. Replace each field as you go with the appropriate data, depending on how you choose to store things. _(It's late here. Good night.)_

Comment: Your Title does not reflect the question you are asking.  You should update it.  This is a template processing/mail merge question.